# Using pyinstaller to convert Python3 and Python2 to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am currently writing a script, on Python 3.

I need to call an already existing Python 2 script, from within my Python 3 script.

In the Python3 script I am doing this using something like:

```
import subprocess
my_command = 'python script_in_py2.py arg1 arg2'
process = subprocess.Popen(my_command.split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Thus, variable `output` will get the output that would be displayed on screen if I had just written `my_command` in terminal.

Although I am currently developing in Ubuntu, eventually I will migrate it to Windows where I will need to convert it to an .exe. For this I have previously used pyinstaller.

I know that running the resulting .exe (of a purely Python3 script) on a Windows machine without Python installed at all works.
However I need to know before going on, whether it will also work like this. My intuition is no (in my knowledge creating a process like that is similar to running the command directly in Terminal/Command Prompt), however I would like to know if anybody knows of a way/workaround. (Installing Python2 on the machine that would run the script is not an option).

Comment: if you run `python script` in your code then you will have to install `Python2` on computer.

Comment: `pyinstaller` doesn't create real `.exe` file (like with C/C++) but it create self-extracting `.zip` file with `python.exe` and your script inside this `.zip`. Maybe better write it all in Python2 and maybe `python script` will works also with python.exe which `pyinstaller` puts in `.exe`

Comment: or better rewrite other scripts so you could `import` them and run function from this scripts - instead of running with subprocess. You could also use `if __name__ == '__main__':` to run it in two different ways.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the comment, however given that it is not a minor script I need to run in 2, I was just wondering if I could do it without delving into rewriting the whole thing in 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be like this:

1. Convert your python2 script i.e. 'script_in_py2.py' into an executable i.e. 'script_in_py2.exe' using pyinstaller.

   `pyinstaller script_in_py2.py`
2. In your python3 script, call this python 2 executable instead of calling python 2 script.

   ```
   import subprocess  
   my_command = 'script_in_py2.exe arg1 arg2'  
   process = subprocess.Popen(my_command.split(), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)  
   output, error = process.communicate()
   ```
3. Now convert your python3 script into an executable using pyinstaller.

   `pyinstaller script_in_py3.py`
4. Paste the executable 'script_in_py2.exe' and 'python27.dll' in dist folder of 'script_in_py3' (i.e. parallel to location of executable 'script_in_py3.exe')
5. Run "script_in_py3.exe" and you will get desired output.

I have tried it on my system and its working smoothly.